# HTML special characters

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the following string :

`&#1575;&#1711;&#1585; &#1576;&#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1607;&#1740;&#1583;`

My question is twofold:

1. What is the encoding of it?
2. How i can parse it to normal characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are HTML entities, which can be decoded using [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php):

```
echo html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

They are UTF8 Entities, decode it with [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Showing them in a browser: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/7tP95/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the script below and it looks like Arabic.

```
<?php
$string='&#1575;&#1711;&#1585; &#1576;&#1582;&#1608;&#1575;&#1607;&#1740;&#1583;';
echo html_entity_decode($string);
?>
```